# SBT unable to resolve any dependencies to their correct paths in basic project

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, ivy

I just started a clean project in Scala using SBT and have run into some issues once attempting to add dependencies. Specifically I tried adding `cats-core` to my dependencies in my `build.sbt` file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
name := "hello-world"
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "2.1.0"
```

My sbt version is set to 1.3.7 in `build.properties`. However once I run compile, it shoots a bunch of angry errors saying it can't resolve the dependency, and rightfully so since the paths it is using don't exist:

```
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.typelevel:cats-core:2.1.0
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /home/lambda/.ivy2/local/org.typelevel/cats-core/2.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/typelevel/cats-core/2.1.0/cats-core-2.1.0.pom
```

I'm a bit confused as I don't seem to be running into this issue on other machines on the same network, however this persists on my local machine despite deleting `~/.ivy2` and `~/.sbt`. I've also tried completely reinstalling sbt, and even building it through a clean Docker image, but the same error persists. It looks to me to be an issue with ivy trying to look for an `ivy.xml` although I'm fairly certain cats uses a `POM.xml`, but I'm unsure how to resolve this. Looking for any help resolving this!

Comment: I've amended that but the error still persists unfortunately!

Comment: Yes -- I ran sbt reload, and even repeated the steps above (deleting cache folders, reinstalling sbt,e tc), but unfortunately it still does not seem to resolve the dependency

Comment: And what is the error you're getting now? The error message (and URL) suggests that you haven't added another `%`.

Comment: Have you experimented with using different resolvers?